# How search in Array with similar data? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I want to search a string in array and get all indexes at which string is present.

My Array consisting of json data coming from server is.

```
["Non Native", "Native", "Native & Non Native"]
```

The method I am using is

```
let indexArray = demand.indices.filter {
   demand[$0].localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Native") 
}
                
print(indexArray)
```

But my problem is I get all of the three indexes. I just want only Native indexes (as in this case second index). (As much as I searched although it is part of other indexes too). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains`, then sure, all three of three of them contain "Native". That is what "contain" means.

Answer (score 3):

You are filtering `contains`, all items *contain* "Native", you have to filter `is equal` aka `compare`

```
let indexArray = demand.indices.filter { demand[$0].localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("Native") == .orderedSame }           
print(indexArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` method, which returns everything that **contains** "Native" while being `case-insensitive`.

It sounds like your goal is to `filter the array` and return only values that are **equal** to "Native"

---

The **previous Answer** has a great solution for accomplishing this. However, here is a more simple one:

```swift
let indexArray = demand.indices.filter { demand[$0] == "Native" }
```